# Xquery version 0.9-ml to xquery version 1.0-ml updation

Tags: xquery, marklogic

We have used these two files from marklogic community/common i.e cookies.xqy and dateparser.xqy

https://github.com/marklogic-community/commons/tree/master/http

https://github.com/marklogic-community/commons/tree/master/dates

now we are looking to switch to the latest version of marklogic i.e 10.0-2.1
and xquery verion 0.9-ml is deprecated in it . so we have to manually do the changes in these files or do we get it from anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `statefull-cookies.xqy` file is in `1.0-ml` syntax already, so you only need to rewrite `cookies.xqy` which would be minor changes, like replacing `define` with `declare` and some extra semi-colons.

The date library might a bit more work, although you could consider using this package instead. It is not an exact match, but pretty powerful, and thoroughly tested in the field:

https://github.com/grtjn/ml-datetime

Feel free to open tickets against it if there is functionality in commons/date lacking in ml-datetime.

HTH!